# laravel sorting eloquent collection based on array matching values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a project recommendation system, where users and projects have required skills tags. I'm trying to generate and sort a collection of recommended projects for users based on the amount of skills that match in each skill array, for example the project that has the most matching skills to users skills would be appear first in the list of recommended projects.

This is my code so far.

```
public function recommendedProjects()
{
    $projects = Project::all()->filter(function ($project) {

        foreach(unserialize($project->skills) as $projectSkill)
        {
            foreach(unserialize(Auth::user()->profile->skills) as $userSkill)
            {
                if($projectSkill === $userSkill)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return View::make('projects.projects')->with("title", "Recommended Projects")->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

So far it kinda works, but only returning projects with at least one matching skill.

It would also be helpful if I could limit the number of results to the most relevant 20 projects or so.

Any help is appreciated, this is my first Laravel project lol.

**EDIT**

I changed my code to store skills in their own table instead of using serialization, right now it returns all projects with at least one matching user skill.

I want to sort the projects so that projects with the most matching skills to user skills appear first.

for example, if a project has 3 required skills that the user has all 3 skills, the project would appear first, over a project with less matching skills.

here is my updated code

```
  $projects = Project::all()->filter(function ($project) {

            foreach ($project->skills as $projectSkill) {
                foreach (Auth::user()->skills as $userSkill) {
                    if ($projectSkill->name === $userSkill->name) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

    });
```

Comment: Couple of things. The unserialising here is bad. You should look into JSON arrays for skills, or even more recommended, create a relation for skills. They really should be their own database model. Unserialising should be done when the object is fetched and not for each project as required. You are also unserialising the users skills multiple times for each project. Way too much overhead. As for the question, there's no reason I can see as to why it is returning one project and not all the projects that match a users skill.

Comment: You should also "eager load" the projects with the skills to prevent the `n+1` problem. [See Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) . Try `Project::with('skills')->get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to sort the collection of projects you have. Try this:

```
$userSkills = Auth::user()->skills;

$projects = Projects::with('skills')->get();

$projects = $projects->sort(function($a, $b) use ($userSkills) {
    // Get the matching skills from both A and B
    $aMatchingSkills = $a->skills->intersect($userSkills);
    $bMatchingSkills = $b->skills->intersect($userSkills);

    // Return the count of A minus the count of B - See PHP uasort
    return $aMatchingSkills->count() - $bMatchingSkills->count();
});
```

This is using the eloquent collection objects pretty extensively (`sort`, `intersect` and `count`). `sort` uses one very useful function from PHP - [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

To remove projects that have no matching skills, try replacing the `Projects::with('skills')->get();` bit with...

```
Projects::with(['skills' => function($q) use ($userSkills) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $userSkills->fetch('name'));
}])->get();
```

This is getting a bit complex now and I can't guarantee that what I've posted will work, but it's close.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work, it just returns all projects.

Comment: Are they sorted now though? I'll edit my question to filter out the projects that have no matching skills.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but you're not saving the `$projects->sort` back to variable, so sorted results are not being used. You need to reassign them back like `$projects = $projects->sort`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. At the time of writing, this method wasn't immutable. I'll update it here though.